# How can I find out when an executing node module is finished?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am testing a node bin script that executes a promise.

Something like this:

```
doSomething()
  .then(() => {
    process.exit(0)
  })
  .catch(() => {
    process.exit(1)
  })
```

If I require this file from a test

```
require('./doSomething.js')
```

It hangs, I have tried `process.on('exit', cb)` but it never fires:

```
require('./doSomething.js')
process.on('exit', () => {
 console.log('done')
})
```

How can I test the action of `doSomething()` from another file by someone gaining access to when this function is finished?

Comment: Does `doSomething.js` work (not hang) when you execute it directly?

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - Really should not have to say that to a 15k rep user with that many badges. It's not a generic question. You either have the code or a specific third party module in mind.

Comment: I'd expect something like: `const doSomething = require( './doSomethings.js' ); doSomething();` When you import a function from another file, you still need to call it in the file importing the function.